# Reading and appending to master page titles?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

what im trying to do is to read the current master page's title, and append something to it from the codebehind of the child page.

I tried to use:

```
this.Master.Page.Title.ToString()
```

But it returned null. Any ideas?

In the master page, here is how i set the title:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>The Magic Finger - Web Design</title>
    <link href="App_Themes/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: If your code is inside a page, use `Title = "Some title";` If you are inside a master page, use `Page.Title = "Some title";`.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but Master.Page refers to the Page control that's being rendered inside the Master. ie: (this == this.Master.Page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Page.Title instead, the title is set by the content page.

Comment: What i want to do is APPEND to the title. So if in the master page the title is "Test", i want so that in the child page i append "Home page", resulting in the final title "Test Home page".

Answer (score 0):

Set the page title as normal in your Master Page.  In your child page, use

```
    Me.Master.Page.Title &= " - This text will be appended"
```

Important: make sure you do not have "Title" as an attribute in the child page's .aspx.  If you have this:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language=""
```

Make sure to remove the title attribute.